# All the (build pipeline) new extensions installed through the marketplace do not show on "Add Task"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-marketplace

Using Azure DevOps (VSTS), when I try add any extension that add build tasks, the extension is shown as "Installed" but the task list isn't updated with the new tasks. I found solutions only for the on premise version of TFS (the classic clear cache folder) but I suppose that I cannot do this in the cloud.

The last time I needed to add an extension was aprox. 1 month ago I had no problems.

For example:
[image: The google play extension is installed but none of it's tasks is shown on the task list]
The google play extension is installed but none of it's tasks is shown on the task list, but it still appear as "Installed"

And on the Extensions page the extension is in the list as expected:
[image: And on the Extensions page the extension is on the list as expected]

Any sugestions on how to "force" the task list to update?

Update:

The problem is not with a parcular extension, another test with some random extension from the marketplace:

[image]
It shows as Installed but the Tasks do not appear.

Comment: I just tried to install this extension and it works well. did you try to uninstall and install again?

Comment: Its not just for this extension, **any** extension that I install/reinstall doens't show up in the task list, I think the problem is with my azure devops organization instead of some particular extension...

Comment: Then you could issue a bug [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) for a quick response from the technical team directly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a ticket for the microsoft team but the issue disappeared overnight (after uninstalling/installing the extesions again in the next day), must have been some regional instability or just god telling me to stop working and go home.

Comment: i was scratching my head on this one as well. uninstall/installing again fixes my problem

Comment: this happens all the time for me

Comment: Still a problem in 2022 I'm afraid. Any resolutions?